# UINavigationBar hiding subviews

Tags: ios5, uinavigationbar

I have a Controller that has a navigation controller and search display controller.

I need to place a Image over the navigation controller view and the search display controller ie:

```
+-------------------------------+
|I|    Title                    |
|I|-----------------------------+
|I| [Search                    ]|
+-------------------------------+
```

I need to place the image in the "I" section. What I am doing is in the viewWillAppear add the view to the navigationController:

```
[self.navigationController.view addSubview:myImage];
```

That is running fine. But the trouble I is when the user start tipping something in the search bar and cancels the search.

In this method I am trying to put the view again over the navigation controller: - (void)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller didHideSearchResultsTableView:(UITableView *)tableView in this way:

```
 [self.navigationController.view addSubview:myImage];
```

But the navigation bar is hiding my image. Is there any way that I can't prevent the navigation bar hiding my subview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your UINavigationcontrolelr is in your main UIWindow, this would add the image to the main window on top of everything else

```
[self.navigationController.view.superview addSubview:myImage];
```